# sometimes the UITableView not displaying data

Tags: iphone, ios4, delegates, uitableview

I am using XCode 4.0.1. I have to different views with UITableView. Data is coming from server. I am parsing JSON data and displaying it to tableview. I am using reloaddata method to display data on tableview. But mostly It is not displaying anything(It is not calling tableview delegate methods) but sometimes functioning normally. I am calling URL at ViewWillAppear, calling reloaddata on connectiondidfinishloadingdata.

I am experienced programmer for iphone but this is unexpected to me. Any Suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try debugging your app? check numberOfRows and connectiondidfinishloadingdata and cellForRowAtIndexPath methods by debugging your app.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should call your update on the main thread.